# Bootstrap-select with selected on top and jQuery sortable integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) for a project and I have an issue with `multiple` lists. I have to meet the following requirements for my app.

### Update:

Based on @caseyjhol  great answer, I started trying to implement this and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7wzv5k0/4/) is a JSFiddle.

## Requirements:

1) I need to render the selected items on top of the lists, not in their original place. This is because if I have a large list, I don't want the user having to scroll down all the list checking for those items that have a tick. Therefore, I render all selected on top, then a divider, and then the none selected.

Let's say the original list is `A B C D E F` in that order. So..if I click on `C`, the list should become `C A B C D E F`. If I then click `E`, it should become `C E A B D F`.

This part of the requirements do work.

2) However, if I now unselect (click) again `E`, then the list should become `C A B D E F`. This part is not working and I don't know how to do it.

3) From the selected items (those that are on the top), I want to allow sorting them via drag and drop using `jQueryUI sortable`. That way, the user can not only select which options but also in which order.

So for example, say I clicked `C`, then `E`, and the list is now as `C E A B D F`. From here, I should be allowed to only sort the `C E` part. Now, let's say that I drag `C` and drop it after `E`. The Bootstrap `<ul>` correctly displays as `E C A B D F` (which is what I need). But now, when I submit the form, the html list has still the old order `C E A B D F`. So I still cannot apply the status of the `<ul>` into the html select.

I tried to document my requirements as much as possible. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have so far, please.

Comment: Ok, hope it is better now, I updated the question quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Each `li` element has a `data-original-index` attribute. That tells you the index of the option in the original `select` element. I'm not sure what your exact usecase is. If you're simply trying to sort the options so that the selected options are at the top, I would think it would make more sense to perform the sorting on the select itself, and then update bootstrap-select with `.selectpicker('refresh')`. If for whatever reason you need to perform the sorting on the `li` elements, I would do something like this:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var $menu = $('#myList').data('selectpicker').$menu,
      $options = $('#myList').find('option');

  function updateOptions() {
    var optionArray = [];

    $menu.find('li').each(function(i, el) {
      optionArray.push($options.eq($(el).data('originalIndex')));
    });
    
    $('#myList').append(optionArray);
    
    // for displaying current order of options
    $('#myList').trigger('showOptions');
  }
  
  // for displaying current order of options
  $('#myList').on('loaded.bs.select showOptions', function() {
    $('#options').empty();
    
    var arr = [];

    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    $('#options').append(arr.join(', '));
  });
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    // move the first li to the end of the list
    $menu.find('li').eq(0).appendTo($menu.find('ul'));

    // for displaying current order of options
    $('#myList').trigger('showOptions');
    
    // update the order of the options to match the list
    updateOptions();
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/master/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/master/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="myList" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option value="Aberdare">Aberdare</option>
    <option value="Berdeen">Berdeen</option>
    <option value="Crington">Crington</option>
</select>

<div id="options"></div>
```

You would need to do a few things differently in produciton (like making sure the originalIndex gets updated properly), but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @caseyjhol. I prepared a JSFiddle with the exact problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/L7wzv5k0/4/   trying to implement your solution. I am sure doing something wrong.  I will be updating the question soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @caseyjhol  Thanks for your great answer. It allowed me to start prototyping a solution. Not yet fully working but it was a start. I created a JSFiddle and updated quite a lot the question. Hope you can help me again ;)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```js
  $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
    var selectedOptions = $(this).find('option:selected');
    selectedOptions.detach();
    $(this).prepend(selectedOptions);
    $(this).selectpicker('refresh');
  });
```

When an option is selected, it detaches the selected options from their current position and prepends them to the top of the list.